# Fuji Aloha 2.0 Seatpost too long?

Tags: seatpost, triathlon

Let me explain my problem. I just bought a used Fuji Aloha 2.0 (56 cm), and the saddle is  a little high for me. Actually, the original seatpost is taking approximately 2.4 inches (6 cm) from me.

[image]

If i get more "flat" seatpost, I believe it will solve my problem. Something like this seatpost. This seatpost is for a DiamondBlack bike, which will not work on a Fuji.

Any ideas or recommendations?

[image]

I highlighted the place that is holding the saddle to go down.

[image]

Comment: Is it new? Or used? Is the saddle 6cm too high? Will it not go any lower? What do you mean by ‘flat’ ?

Comment: Is this your bike, [2009 Aloha 2.0](https://images.app.goo.gl/63BvMgeyLVRBdiXC8)?

Comment: What is stopping you from lowering the seatpost?  Is it too long?  Why not carefully trim 5cm off the bottom and refit?

Comment: Bike is used. I highlighted the spot where it's holding the saddle to go lower.

Comment: Yes that thing holding the saddle needs to go lower. What is stopping it from going lower?

Comment: @Swifty From that point, the seatpost gets a little larger and it stops it. I saw the message about trimming it, but i was wondering if there is any seatpost like the one that i posted in the original message. Hope it makes sense. Appreciate your attention.

Comment: Do you mean the seat post is too fat to go in further, so trimming the length wouldn’t solve that problem?

Comment: @Swifty , yes! Too fat... Length is not a problem. That was my initial thought, but the seatpost has plenty of space to "go down". Do you think i can not find another seatpost in the market?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to insert the seatpost farther than it already is then the frame is likely too large for you. The seatpost should never be all the way inserted and touching the frame and I do not think there are any seatposts that will let you do this.

My suggestion would be to buy a 54cm bike instead or if that is not an option buy some clipless pedals and put some cleat shims on that will give you a few extra cm at the pedals.